# Problems with XSLT: No Tags in the output

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I am stuck with a XSL transformation and I've tried many things all day long. Obviously I am not an expert on this.

Can you help me to understand what's wrong with my XSL file ?

This is my source XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PublishPFTEST xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" creationDateTime="2017-08-18T17:20:13-03:00" transLanguage="EN" baseLanguage="EN" messageID="7584270.1503087614245122357" maximoVersion="7 6 20161014-1020 V7606-50" event="1">
  <PFTESTSet>
    <WORKORDER action="Add">
      <ASSETNUM>MPC1234</ASSETNUM>
      <DESCRIPTION>WOTEST</DESCRIPTION>
      <WONUM>WO123</WONUM>
      <SITEID>BEDFORD</SITEID>

    </WORKORDER>
  </PFTESTSet>
</PublishPFTEST>
```

My XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <TemplateSet>
            <xsl:for-each select="/PublishPFTEST/PFTESTSet/WORKORDER">
                <asset>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ASSETNUM"/>
                </asset>
                <desc>
                    <xsl:value-of select="DESCRIPTION"/>
                </desc>

            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </TemplateSet>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is the transformed XML file... It shows other data, and no XML tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TemplateSet xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">


      MPC1234
      WOTEST
      WO123
      BEDFORD



</TemplateSet>
```

Sorry for the dummy question.

Comment: Search for "XSLT default namespace" for 1000 answers to this question. Or at any rate, to the question that you would have asked if you had only known that default namespaces were the issue.

Comment: @MichaelKay, Like I said I spent all day trying too many things - and I couldn't make it to work. SO was my last resort.  Thanks for the feedback thou.

Have a great day.

Comment: Yes, it's a tough one. Someone falls into this elephant trap everyday, and it's hard to tell them what they did wrong in terms of their approach to solving the problem. For most people, I think the lesson to learn is that it's worth spending a day or two reading books about a new technology before you start coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the text is showing up in the output because of [XSLT's built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#built-in-rule). To resolve that issue, you should remove the `<xsl:apply-templates/>` so no other processing is done.

There are no new XML elements output because your `xsl:for-each` never selects anything. This is because your XML is using the default namespace `http://www.ibm.com/maximo`. You can bind that namespace to a prefix and use it in your XPath's.

Example of both suggestions (I also added `exclude-result-prefixes="m"` so the namespace wouldn't be output)...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:m="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="m">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <TemplateSet>
      <xsl:for-each select="/m:PublishPFTEST/m:PFTESTSet/m:WORKORDER">
        <asset>
          <xsl:value-of select="m:ASSETNUM"/>
        </asset>
        <desc>
          <xsl:value-of select="m:DESCRIPTION"/>
        </desc>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </TemplateSet>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hey Daniel,

Thank you so much... your suggestions indeed made it !  

I will carefuly review the solution to understand what was wrong and of course learn from it.

Again, thank you very much.

Regards

Comment: @MarcioCorrêa, And why also not accept the answer? Please, respect the time people take to answer and help.

Comment: Dimitre,  I voted it up, but the SO says it does not count because I have no reputation enough.  I just started using StackOverfow so forgive me.

I do respect all the assistance I get, not only here but anywhere - Please don't judge.

Comment: @MarcioCorrêa - I believe Dimitre was only requesting that the answer be accepted (by clicking the checkmark next to it) which hadn't been done at the time of his comment. You did accept my answer and I greatly appreciate it. Thanks and welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem which was caused by multiple entries in the Transformation Pipeline in Eclipse. Just remove the duplicate and/or multiple entries and leave just the single one you need. Worked for me!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Output which doesn't contain any XML tags has nothing to do with the question?